# Lambda function change endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I am somewhat new to Lambda and am trying to pull some data from Support(us-east-1) and then Read/Write to a DynamoDB(I am using a local dynamodb-local instance), however I dont know how to change the region.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
});

const support = new AWS.Support({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  apiVersion: '2013-04-15'
});

const supportParams = {
  checkId: 'Qch7DwouX1',
  language: 'en'
};

let stuff = {};

support.describeTrustedAdvisorCheckResult(supportParams, (err, data) => {
  if(err) console.log('Error: ', err.stack);
  else {
     stuff[test] = [...data]
  };
}

// Now I want to pull some data from DynamoDB locally or in another region
//
// AWS.config.update({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000});
//
```

How do I change the endpoint to http://localhost:8000 or us-west-2 to get something from DynamoDB?  Am I not supposed to change region/endpoint within 1 lambda function?

I was trying something like:

```
const dynaDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000'})
const dynaClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

dynaClient.scan({}, (err, data) => {
  ..
  ..
  ..
}
```

Comment: What's a region of your lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the same problem when we want to copy between two regions.

You can instantiate aws-sdk one for each dynamodb,

```
const AWSregion = require('aws-sdk');
AWSregion.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
});
// Connect to us-east-1 with AWSregion

const AWSlocal = require('aws-sdk');  // Don't set any region here, since it is local
// Connect to local dynamodb with AWSlocal
```

Hope it helps.